# debugging simple LISP functions.

Tags: recursion, lisp, funcall

I am very new to lisp, and am having a hard time even getting my feet wet. I'm sure once, I have a few functions working, I'll be able to build upon them and work on higher order functions, and more complex problems.

Can someone point out my errors in the following code.

```
(defun indeHelper(A L N)
 (cond (Null N) nil)
 ((= A (first L) (cons N (indeHelper A (rest L) (+ 1 N)))))
 (t (indeHelper A (rest L) (+ 1 N))))

(defun inde(A L)
  (funcall indeHelper(A L 1)))
```

Also how would I call this? I have one function I think is working ok, but I can't get the syntax for calling it.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have basic syntax issues, which should be apparent from the indentation in the first function. Notice that the 3rd and 4th lines are not indented relative to `(cond`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of syntax issues.

The syntax of `COND` is:

```
(cond (test1 body1...)
      (test2 body2...)
      ...)
```

Your `test1` is supposed to be `(null n)`, and `body1` should be `nil`, but you didn't wrap them in a level of parentheses. Then your other tests and bodies are outside `cond`, as should be apparent from the indentation.

It should be:

```
(defun indeHelper(A L N)
  (cond ((Null N) nil)
        ((= A (first L) (cons N (indeHelper A (rest L) (+ 1 N)))))
        (t (indeHelper A (rest L) (+ 1 N)))))
```

In the second function, you don't need to use `funcall`. That's used when you're calling a dynamically-determined function (e.g. when writing higher-order functions), but you're just calling a known function. It should just be:

```
(defun inde(A L)
  (indeHelper A L 1))
```

If you did need to use `funcall`, the syntax is:

```
(funcall someVariable A L 1)
```

When using `funcall`, the arguments aren't put into a nested list, they're just ordinary arguments to `funcall`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, this will set me in the right direction!